# explain int class_constructor:: member

Tags: c++

I have faced a c++ program like this: 
class `test` has one static member `i`
then explicitly initialized to like this 
`int test::x`
Can somebody explain this line ? How `i` is initialized to `0` here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not initialization. That's a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Because `x` is a `static` member, `int test::x;` is actually equivalent to `int test::x = 0;`.

Unlike variables with automatic storage initialisation, `static` numeric-type variables are initialised to zero.

Comment: can I do it within class like define i within constructor as (public : test() { i=0} ;

Comment: I have some doubts not much clear about the concepts.. can you refer some books/tutors ..

Comment: Trying to clarify the doubts :